# Swift MacOS array of buttons call function with argument

Tags: arrays, swift, nsbutton

I have a playing field for a board game similar to chess with 60 fields. Instead of connecting them manually in storyboard I want to do it with a for...in.
My code is like this:

```
let feld = NSButton()
feld.frame = CGRect(x: 1300+30*h, y: 20, width: 22, height: 22)
feld.target = self
feld.action = #selector(ButtonTest)
self.view.addSubview(feld)
ButtonArray.append(feld)
```

And the function like this (I dont understand why I need @objc before the function but only this way it works.

```
@objc func ButtonTest() {
ButtonArray[2].isEnabled=false
}
```

The code work fine. But I want to pass an argument to the function so I can deactivate the button just being pressed and not only [2] like in this example.
(and I want to add other calculations to this function).

I searched around and it seems that one cannot pass arguments. If that is true how else can I solve my problem?

EDIT:
Great answer and explanation, thanks. I sadly asked the question imprecisely: I dont only want to deactivate the pressed button but also
do calculations like this:

```
var score = 5+/NumberOfButtonPressed/
```

So if the first button is pressed var score=6, if the 10th button is pressed score=15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `@objc` because otherwise, the Swift compiler will not create a selector for the method. A selector is an Objective-C value that identifies a method, and it is necessary to call a method through Objective-C. (Cocoa is written in Objective-C.) You can get a method's selector using `#selector`, as you have already found.

On macOS, actions called through Cocoa take 0 or 1 additional parameters. The optional parameter is the "sender", which is the object that triggered the action (the button on which you clicked). Try this:

```
@objc
func ButtonTest(sender: NSButton?) {
    sender?.isEnabled = false
}
```

You don't need to change the `#selector()` expression. The Cocoa runtime will call your method with that parameter just by virtue of it existing.

Comment: In a target / action `selector` method the `sender` is never optional if the parameter is specified.

Comment: @vadian, due to how parameters are passed on every platform that Cocoa supports, it is optional. This is [documented behavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Target-Action/Target-Action.html) (see bottom) for iOS, and implied to be true for macOS (although, AFAIK, the third signature is not supported).

Comment: @vadian, sorry, I misread your comment (thought you said that the parameter itself has to be present). I don't actually know about that.

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding: The parameter per se is optional. But if the parameter is specified, the **type** of the parameter is non-optional (without question mark).